# Python - Why does fnmatch match files in subdirs?

Tags: python, filenames

Why does this return `True`:

```
fnmatch('/home/user/a/b', '/home/user/*')
```

while `ls -d /home/user/*` doesn't give `/home/user/a/b` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fnmatch` сhecks only names (strings) - without verification of the existence of real files.

To check file existence you may use `os.path.exists(path)` call. Like this:

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch
from os.path import exists

pattern = '/home/user/*'
name = '/home/user/a/b'

if exists(name):
    if fnmatch(name, pattern):
        print('"{}" exists and matches'.format(name))
```